Functional Extensionality for Propositional Functions
I've created the following simple definitions for representing sets of objects of type X as functions X -> Prop and defined various operations such as cup (union). However, before I get started actually using them, I wanted to prove some basic facts about them that might be useful later on. But very early on I hit a snag with proving cup a b = cup b a (using the axiom of functional extensionality). A minimal example:
Require Import Setoid.

Axiom func_eq : forall (X Y : Type) (f g : X -> Y), (forall (x : X), f x = g x) -> f = g.

Definition cup {X : Type} (a b : X -> Prop) : X -> Prop := fun (x : X) => a x \/ b x.

Theorem cup_comm : forall (X : Type) (a b : X -> Prop), cup a b = cup b a.
Proof.
    intros. apply func_eq. intros. unfold cup.
    rewrite or_comm. (* <-------- ERROR HERE *)

However, this gives me the following setoid rewrite error:
setoid rewrite failed: Unable to satisfy the following constraints:
UNDEFINED EVARS:
 ?X17==[X a b x |- relation Prop] (internal placeholder) {?r}
 ?X18==[X a b x (do_subrelation:=Morphisms.do_subrelation) |-
         Morphisms.Proper (iff ==> ?r ==> Basics.flip Basics.impl) eq]
         (internal placeholder) {?p}
 ?X19==[X a b x |- Morphisms.ProperProxy ?r (b x \/ a x)]
         (internal placeholder) {?p0}
TYPECLASSES:?X17 ?X18 ?X19
SHELF:||
FUTURE GOALS STACK:?X19 ?X18 ?X17||

Since the error mentioned UNDEFINED EVARS, I tried to clear as much as possible out of the proof state before attempting the rewrite. With remember and clear I can even get the proof state to be simply P, Q: Prop with goal P \/ Q = Q \/ P.
It also looks like I hit a similar snag trying to prove forall (P Q : Prop), (P <-> Q) -> P = Q as trying to rewrite with the hypothesis fails. I know it's possible to rewrite with iff, so I'm assuming this is just an issue with proving equivalence of propositions.
However, if I switch the normal = form of functional equivalence to a biconditional version, it seems I'm able to prove this:
Require Import Setoid.

Axiom func_eq_iff : forall (X : Type) (f g : X -> Prop), (forall (x : X), f x <-> g x) -> f = g.

Definition cup {X : Type} (a b : X -> Prop) : X -> Prop := fun (x : X) => a x \/ b x.

Theorem cup_comm : forall (X : Type) (a b : X -> Prop), cup a b = cup b a.
Proof.
    intros. unfold cup. apply func_eq_iff. intros. rewrite or_comm. reflexivity.
Qed.

So, is my only option to use this <-> form of functional equivalence rather than the normal = version? Also, does anyone know if this form is logically consistent to include as an axiom? I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't be, but then again the error from the normal version of functional extensionality has me questioning that...
edit
For the second part of the question, I noticed that the iff form of functional extensionality can actually be proven with a simpler axiom of (P <-> Q) <-> (P = Q), and while writing this @Naïm Favier later mentioned this was consistent.
So I guess only my first question remains: is this (or another similar) axiom the only way to prove this theorem? It just seems strange since I've never had rewrite with a biconditional fail like this before.

Propositional extensionality is consistent, if that's what you're asking. Your func_eq_iff combines funext and propext.

The concept you are describing here is called "propositional extensionality," It is often assumed as an axiom in Coq, see https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/CoqAndAxioms for example. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76463859/is-prop-extensionality-inconsistent-in-coq.

Coq has an Extensionality_Ensembles axiom which packages everything you need into one assumption.
From Coq Require Import Ensembles.

Definition cup {X : Type} (a b : X -> Prop) : X -> Prop :=
  fun (x : X) => a x \/ b x.

Theorem cup_comm : forall (X : Type) (a b : X -> Prop), cup a b = cup b a.
Proof.
  intros X a b.
  apply Extensionality_Ensembles.
  firstorder.
Qed.


The goal of setoid rewrite is to rewrite goal where the logical relation used is not equality but a setoid relation like logical equivalence, that is rewrite goals of the form R X Y, here X <-> Y but not to rewrite goals of the form X = Y using that R Y Z or here Y <-> Z. For instance:
Require Import Setoid.

Section Foo.

  Context (A B C : Prop).
  Context (HAB : A <-> B).
  Context (HBC : B <-> C).

  Definition HAC : A <-> C.
    rewrite HAB. 

As mentioned, in your case, in the absence of the axiom of Proposition Extensionality: (A <-> B -> A = B), there is no reason why A would be equal to B.
You can check the paper "The Next 700 Syntactical Models of Type Theory" for a simple argument why it does not hold automatically.
